# AdobeSign Integration Key

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, adobe, sign

I'm building a service that should be able to generate Adobe Sign agreements on the background. This basically means that I can't use the OAuth authentication flow.

In AdobeSign user account settings you can generate an Integration Key which gives permanent access to any service - so this is exactly what I am looking for.

However, all the recent AdobeSign docs only describe OAuth flow so I got 0 clues on how to actually use it.

If anyone has done this before and knows an API signature for an AdobeSign authentication using an Integration Key, can you please share it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question and after a bunch of googling came across [this medium article](https://medium.com/adobetech/adobe-sign-tutorial-everything-you-need-to-effectively-use-the-adobe-sign-api-9d9f135c347d).

Pertinent quote from the article:

> Important: All calls to our API are made in the “context” of a user. There are two “header” parameters which should be in every call.

`"Authorization": "Bearer **** Your Integration key Here****`

`"x-api-user": "email:yoursender@yourdomain.com"`

> You can skip the “x-api-user” param but the call will still be made in the context of the token owner. A best practice is to include this, so that the API logs show who the initiator is.